# Unable to count checked checkboxes from another page with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple sets of checkboxes. I want to count a particular set of checkboxes. These checkboxes have the class `sub`. The interesting part is, they are fetched by an ajax call from another php page. So the counter isn't working.

```
<script>
$("[id^=sub][type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    $('#count').text($("[id^=sub][type=checkbox]").length);
});
</script>
```

When I use the below script to get the checkboxes which are in the html page itself, it counts the very first set of the checkboxes! These are the checkboxes clicked to fetch those `sub` checkboxes!

Now, how do I count that particular set of checkboxes with the `sub` class which are fetched by the ajax call?

```
<script>
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $('#count').text($("input:checkbox:checked").length);
});
</script>
```

This is the structure of the fetched checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="sub['.$subjects_id.']" id="sub" value="">
```

And I display the count in the html page like this:

```
<p id="count"></p>
```

Comment: “_So the counter isn't working_” What does that mean? Is it `0`? Is it `undefined`? Is it `null`? Is it `12` although it should be `41`? Does it throw a `TypeError`? Does it do exactly nothing at all? Please explain in detail. Also I don’t see any AJAX call in your codes.

Comment: @Xufox that means it's not showing any count!

Comment: So is it an error that you can see in your console output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are binding the change-event handler to the sub checkboxes, they don't exist, so the jQuery object does not represent any elements. That is, `$("[id^=sub][type=checkbox]")` does not match any elements when you call it.

You have two choices, bind the event handlers after the checkboxes are created by the ajax call, or use event delegation. With event delegation, you bind the handler to an ancestor element, but specify that it be called only when an element matching a selector is changed. You can see the jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function documentation for more about event delegation.

It can be as easy as:

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^=sub][type=checkbox]', function () {
    $('#count').text($('[id^=sub][type=checkbox]:checked').length);
});
```

But for efficiency, you should try to use a closer ancestor than the `document` element. The closer the better, but it must be an ancestor of all the sub checkboxes, and it must exist when this code is executed.

According to the html you show for the sub checkboxes, you could also use the following selector:

```
$(document).on('change', ':checkbox.sub', function () {
    $('#count').text($(':checkbox.sub:checked').length);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqdb45gk/)

Comment: Event delegation is a really elegant solution here. No need for hundreds of event listeners when there could be only one.

Comment: @John S , i tried your exact code, it's still not showing the count. I tried using $('td') in place of document a syou ask to choose the closest ancestor, still not showing the count!

Comment: @sweety - Try with `document` first.

Comment: @JohnS, i did, still not

Comment: @sweety - I can only imagine that your selector is not matching the checkboxes. You could post the actual html for the checkboxes in your question. You could also try the following selector: `:checkbox.sub`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqdb45gk/1/)

Comment: @ i tried as per your fiddle, it worked..must include the library.